# PHP & MySQL checked checkbox problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if the checkbox has been checked and display the check mark for the user to see when they check there account settings. I want to know how can I fix this problem using PHP so that the check mark is displayed every time the user views their account settings?

Here is the HTML.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean which attribute do you set so that the checkbox is checked?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="yes" checked="checked" />
```

EDIT: What I would do, is bind some code to the checkbox's click event (using a library like jQuery), like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#privacy_policy").click(function() {

        // block the checkbox
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var checked = 0;
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            checked = 1;
        }

        // send the checked state to PHP script
        // if the update has been successful, the script echos a '1'
        $.post('account.php', { checked: checked, function(resp) {

            // update has been successful
            if(resp == 1) {

                // unblock the checkbox, the current 
                // checked state reflects the stored value
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                alert("settings could not be updated");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

That will handle the real-time manipulating of that particular option's setting every time the checkbox is clicked. (I think that's what you meant, anyway). You just need to act on the `$_POST['checked']` variable internally.

To set up the initial state of the checkbox based on a stored value (the first time the page loads), just use short tags, e.g.:

```
<?php
$isChecked = $_SESSION['someSetting']; // 1 or 0, for example
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="yes" <?php if($isChecked) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/>
```

Comment: I want to display the check mark only when the user checks and then display it all the time until the user unchecks it.

Comment: Did you want it to always appear when the user is on your site, i.e. a check-mark for a particular preference? In that case, you need a way to have it saved for a particular user's preference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is. If you know in PHP whether the checkbox should be checked, you can do something like

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="yes"';
if ($somevar) echo ' checked="checked" ';
echo ' />';
```

This will make the checkbox default to being checked if `$somevar` is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $checked = $someBoolean ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="yes"<?php echo $checked; ?> />
```

Where `$someBoolean` holds a boolean (true/false) value whether it was checked before or not (value retrieved from a database for instance).

If `true` it will result in:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="yes" checked="checked" />
```

else:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the user's settings stored in a database of some description. Assuming this is MYSQL do the following:

```
$query = "
    SELECT privacy_policy FROM user_settings WHERE user_id = $user_id
    ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$user_settings = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

This assumes that the information is stored a column called "privacy_policy" in a table called user_settings and that you already know the $user_id. The privacy policy setting is now held in `$user_settings['privacy_policy']`. I'm also assuming that it is a boolean where true means you want it checked and false means you don't want it checked.

You might also instead be getting the setting from a user input, such as after just changing the variable. In this case, just find the variable in your $_POST or $_GET e.g. $_POST['privacy_policy'] and continue with that variable instead.

So now do the following:

if($user_settings['privacy_policy']) $checked = "checked='checked'";
   else $checked = '';
   echo "';

If $user_sesstings['privacy_policy'] is true, $checked will be set and echoed along with the rest of the checkbox. Otherwise, the checkbox will be echoed without the attribute and so will be unchecked.